# How to make a class their object can directly initializable like integer class in java

Tags: java

I want to know about that how can I make a class their object directly initializable without using constructor like integer class, float class, string class.

Like my class is:

```
public class var{
    //here some data
}
```

And I want to do like that

```
var v = 10;  not 
var v = new var(10);
```

So how can I do that?

Comment: You cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

For `String s = "asd";` there's compiler (and other) trickery involved, and for `Integer i = 10;` there's autoboxing involved. Neither of those is available for the common developer.

Comment: But string and Integer, that are also class then why we can't do like that in our class

Comment: Because they're classes in the JDK. They can get all sorts of preferential treatment not available to you.

Comment: But Java is open source how it is not available for me

Comment: Because your classes aren't JDK classes. You could create a preprocessor or your own compiler to get that functionality, or you could use something like Kotlin if you want to write "Java" in a different way. But out of the box, you can't do it. It's not for you.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that with pure Java. `float`s and `int`s are called **primitive** datatypes. They are built into the compiler. The [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) says that it is predefined in the language and uses a reserved keyword. As for `String`s, the compiler sees the literal and interns it (using quotes as an initializer) and you can't do it too. But if you create a compiler for the JVM, you can create your own primitive types or "syntax sugar" like `Strings`)

Comment: A String literal is not a primitive datatype.

Comment: Yes, but the question wasn't only about floats and integers.